# More information on Kruskal's treatment of Surreal numbers as an asymptotic behavior of a real valued function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, asymptotics, nonstandard-analysis, surreal-numbers, surreal-analysis

The only way that I could think about Surreal numbers is how Conway defined them inductively, with the two axioms and so on. I can't find any information about Kruskal's point of view and would very much appreciate it if someone could explain more.

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/pdf/0801.4877v5.pdf.